# Looking for this stl design for a cellphone clamp

Tags: stl, part-identification

I've searched, and surprisingly I am not able to find this design on Thingiverse:

[image]

Where can I find this 3d model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This file simply is not on Thingiverse. Not all files are on Thingiverse.

A Google reverse-image-search for that picture in all size told me that the image stems from an [all3dp article](https://all3dp.com/2/best-3d-printer-camera-monitor-3d-printer/), and they have a reference link to [Pinshape](https://assets.pinshape.com/uploads/image/file/155113/universal-phone-tripod-mount-3d-printing-155113.jpg) as it is presented here:

[image: As seen on all3dp]

The file name of the linked picture is `universal-phone-tripod-mount-3d-printing-155113.jpg`

Taking that as a search term lead me to pinshape model [37196: 3d printed universal phone-tripod mount](https://pinshape.com/items/37196-3d-printed-universal-phone-tripod-mount) by [jakejake](https://pinshape.com/users/220819-jakejake)